# Strange Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am programming a simple heapify algorithm. It needs to work on big data size, the size being 100,000 and the numbers in the range 0 to 10^9.

The algorithm works for size somewhere around 25,000. But if data set becomes greater than that, it starts to throw segmentation faults.

I have used unsigned long long int throughout, so I dont see where the problem is. I am using vectors to store my data, and all data is of types long long int.

Has anyone encountered such problems before ?

Here is the heapify procedure I'm using :

```
vector<unsigned long long> array;
vector<unsigned long long> orig_index;
vector<unsigned long long> new_index;

unsigned long long heapify (unsigned long long count) {

unsigned long long temp, left, right, min;
long long j;
unsigned long long n_swaps = 0;


for(long long i=(count%2 ? (count-2)/2 : (count-1)/2 ); i>=0; --i) {
    left=  (2*i)+1 ;
    right= (2*i)+2 ;



    j= i;
    while( ( (array[j] > array[left])  && left<count) || ( (array[j] > array[right]) && (right<count) ) ){

        //Swap

        //Find lesser of left or right
        if(right>= count) {
            min= array[left];
        } else {
            min= array[left] > array[right] ? array[right] : array[left];
        }

            if(array[j] > array[left] && (min== array[left])) {
            temp= array[j];
            array[j]= array[left] ;
            array[left]= temp;

            //Update indexes
            orig_index.push_back(j);
            new_index.push_back(left);

            j= left;
            right= (2*left)+2 ;
            left=  (2*left)+1 ;
            ++n_swaps;
        }
        else if ( (right < count) && (array[j] > array[right]) ) {
            temp= array[j];
            array[j]= array[right] ;
            array[right]= temp;

            //Update indexes
            orig_index.push_back(j);
            new_index.push_back(right);

            j= right;
            left=  (2*right)+1 ;
            right= (2*right)+2 ;
            ++n_swaps;
        }

    }
}
return n_swaps;
}
```

Here is the random data generator function I'm using. Count is size of data here (like 20k or 30k) and max is the range.

```
void generate(unsigned long long count, unsigned long long max) {
srand( time(NULL) );
//Dummy array of max size
vector<unsigned long long> dummy;

//Populate the dummy
for(unsigned long long i=0; i<max; ++i) {
    dummy.push_back(i);
}

//Select random number from dummy, swap with last and pop
unsigned long long temp;
unsigned long long swap;
unsigned long long dummy_size= max-1;

cout<<"****************Indices************"<<endl;
for(unsigned long long i=0; i<count; ++i) {
    temp= rand() % dummy_size ;
    cout<<temp<<endl;
    array.push_back( dummy[temp] );

    //Swap and pop
    swap= dummy[temp];
    dummy[temp] = dummy[dummy_size];
    dummy[dummy_size] = swap;
    --dummy_size;
}
cout<<"*************End*****************"<<endl;
dummy.clear();
}
```

The main function

```
int main(void) {

unsigned long long count= 25000;
unsigned long long max= 1000000 ;

//Generate random numbers and push on array
generate(count, max);

//Print array
for(unsigned long long i=0; i<array.size(); ++i) {
    cout<<array[i]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;

//Build heap
unsigned long long n_swaps = heapify(count);

cout<<n_swaps<<"\n";
for(unsigned long long i=0; i<orig_index.size(); ++i) {
    cout<<orig_index[i]<<" "<<new_index[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

I hope the algorithms are correct, but just cant find why segmentation fault is happening for big data sets, and not small ones.

Comment: stack overflow?... ;)

Comment: @InnocentBystander. So then how do I solve it ? How do I test it on big set ?

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler - *I am using vectors to store my data* -- And you should be using `vector::at()` when accessing your vector items instead of `[ ]` to ensure you are not going out of bounds (this may not be a "big data" issue).  If you are going out-of-bounds, an `out_of_range` exception will be thrown instead of a segmentation fault, thus giving you more information.  Also, where is you `main` function showing how you're calling these functions?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie. The main function has nothing just calling generator and heapify, and finally printing the vectors. Also are you sure it's the out of range thing, since the program always runs for around 25k data size.

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler You should be posting the function here, so that we can easily copy and paste it into the editor, compile it, and see the results.  We shouldn't have to write code ourselves.  Second, going out-of-bounds is undefined behavior, so it doesn't matter what data size you have.  There is no way to know for sure until you change your code to use `at()`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie. Ive added the main.

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler -  Please [see this](http://ideone.com/V3lJn8).  Told you so.  Note where I used `at()` instead of `[ ]`.  The `while` loop, and the code that swaps.

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler And to prove this was not a "big data" issue, here is the same code, [but using smaller values](http://ideone.com/NuDeIY).  This is why I stated that using `[ ]` and going out of bounds is undefined behavior.  Your code really wasn't working, but you believed it was.  Using `at()` will always throw an exception as soon as you go out of bounds -- no random segmentation faults can happen.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie. Yes. Thanks, although I didnt happen to run across any problems in small set, but I guess it was there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The && is evaluated from left to right(as write order), so I changed a line and this no "crash", (segmentation-fault).

```
while( ( (array[j] > array[left])  && left<count) || ( (array[j] > array[right]) && (right<count) ) ){
```

replaced by:

```
while( ( left<count && (array[j] > array[left])) || ( (right<count) && (array[j] > array[right]) ) ){
```

Complete code:

```
using namespace std;

vector<unsigned long long> array;
vector<unsigned long long> orig_index;
vector<unsigned long long> new_index;

unsigned long long heapify(unsigned long long count) {
  unsigned long long temp, left, right, min;
  long long j;
  unsigned long long n_swaps = 0;

  for (long long i = (count % 2 ? (count - 2) / 2 : (count - 1) / 2); i >= 0;
       --i) {
    left = (2 * i) + 1;
    right = (2 * i) + 2;

    j = i;
    while ((left < count && (array[j] > array[left])) ||
           ((right < count) && (array[j] > array[right]))) {
      // Swap

      // Find lesser of left or right
      if (right >= count) {
        min = array[left];
      } else {
        min = array[left] > array[right] ? array[right] : array[left];
      }

      if (array[j] > array[left] && (min == array[left])) {
        temp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[left];
        array[left] = temp;

        // Update indexes
        orig_index.push_back(j);
        new_index.push_back(left);

        j = left;
        right = (2 * left) + 2;
        left = (2 * left) + 1;
        ++n_swaps;
      } else if ((right < count) && (array[j] > array[right])) {
        temp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[right];
        array[right] = temp;

        // Update indexes
        orig_index.push_back(j);
        new_index.push_back(right);

        j = right;
        left = (2 * right) + 1;
        right = (2 * right) + 2;
        ++n_swaps;
      }
    }
  }
  return n_swaps;
}

void generate(unsigned long long count, unsigned long long max) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  // Dummy array of max size
  vector<unsigned long long> dummy;

  // Populate the dummy
  for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
    dummy.push_back(i);
  }

  // Select random number from dummy, swap with last and pop
  unsigned long long temp;
  unsigned long long swap;
  unsigned long long dummy_size = max - 1;

  cout << "****************Indices************" << endl;
  for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    temp = rand() % dummy_size;
    cout << temp << endl;
    array.push_back(dummy[temp]);

    // Swap and pop
    swap = dummy[temp];
    dummy[temp] = dummy[dummy_size];
    dummy[dummy_size] = swap;
    --dummy_size;
  }
  cout << "*************End*****************" << endl;
  dummy.clear();
}

int main(void) {
  unsigned long long count = 25000;
  unsigned long long max = 1000000;

  // Generate random numbers and push on array
  generate(count, max);

  // Print array
  for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
    cout << array[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;

  // Build heap
  unsigned long long n_swaps = heapify(count);

  cout << n_swaps << "\n";
  for (unsigned long long i = 0; i < orig_index.size(); ++i) {
    cout << orig_index[i] << " " << new_index[i] << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for that. Now before reading the array we are checking if indexes are within bounds. That did it !

Comment: Good luck and happy coding :).